# NPM Install loop

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I'm trying to push changes to an azure git repo for a web application with node server back end.

I'm getting an error on the Kudo console for a missing module:

> Cannot find module \'cors\'

So I go to the debug console and run npm i cors. 
I then try to open the website in the browser again - errors out.

> Please install mysql2 package manually

Kudo debug console - npm i mysql2

Run the site again, back to:

> Cannot find module \'cors\'

This continues in an endless loop. Any suggestions as to what is happening here?

Comment: I've had issues with this when using older versions of NPM. I was able to fix this by adding everything to my `package.json` then running `npm install`. Installing packages 1 by 1 tended to have problems with deleting packages I did end up needing.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. Deleted the node_modules folder, deleted package-lock.json and tried npm install, same error

Comment: Are `cors` and `mysql2` both in your package.json dependencies?

Comment: Good call. They were in 'devDependencies'. Just copied them over and re-deploying now

Comment: If this issue has been resolved, you can add your solution to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run npm `install cors --save` from the command line in the main project directory to install it and add it to your `package.json`

It is possible that the `cors` module was separated from the main express package.

Hope it helps.